# Redux store not up to date in component did update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a React container for user login. When it mounts it fetches some third-party scripts and injects them into the page (this creates a login widget)

The login phase is in two parts, the first part is to log in to the third party system, on completion of that I then need to login to a second system using the payload from the first.

On `componentDidMount` I fire a request to fetch the third party scripts, all is good here.

When I click on the login button (its a pre-built widget provided by the third-party that fires a callback we can hook into, no need to create the widget etc itself), the callback fires and we get a customer token back, again all good here.

The part that I'm having trouble with using that customer token, I use redux to add it to the store, inside `componentDidUpdate` I then check prevProps against current props to check for the token, if it exists I fire an action to log in to the second system. I wanted to avoid this action firing multiple times so once its fired once I add a `hasRequested` field to the store and then check against this in `componentDidUpdate` to safeguard against it getting called multiple times.

This bit doesn't work, because I have multiple instances of the `LoginContainer` on the page, the `componentDidUpdate` is firing multiple times and the store isn't getting updated in time with the `hasRequested` value, the outcome being that I end up making multiple API requests.

Anyone got any ideas how I can have multiple instances of a container but limit the number of times an action fires when its props update?

Sample code below

LoginContainer

```
class LoginContainer extends Component {
  /**
   * componentDidMount
   */
  componentDidMount () {
    if (!this.props.thirdPartyCode.hasRequested) {
      this.props.fetchThirdPartySriptsAndLoad();
    }
  }

  /**
   * componentDidUpdate
   */
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (
      prevProps.authentication.customerToken !== this.props.authentication.customerToken
      && !this.props.authentication.hasRequested
    ) {
      this.props.authenticateUserWithSecondSystem();
    }
  }
```

Authentication reducer

```
import {
  SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST,
  SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_SUCCESS,
  SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_FAILURE,
} from 'actions/authentication/authentication-actions';

export const defaultState = {
  isFetching: false,
  hasRequested: false,
  error: '',
  customerToken: ''
};

/**
 * Reducer for authentication
 * @param {Object} state
 * @param {Object} action
 * @returns {Object} updated state
 */
export default function (state = defaultState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        hasRequested: true
      });
    case SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false
      });
```

Authentication actions

```
export const SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST = 'SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST';
export const SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_SUCCESS = 'SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_SUCCESS';
export const SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_FAILURE = 'SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_FAILURE';

/**
 * Request Authenticate
 * @returns {{type: string}}
 */
function requestSecondSystemAuthentication () {
  return {
    type: SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST
  };
}

/**
 * Authenticate Success
 * @param {Object} data - response data
 * @returns {{type: string}}
 */
function secondSystemAuthenticateSuccess (data) {
  return {
    type: SECOND_SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATE_SUCCESS,
    data
  };
}

/**
 * Post Authenticate
 * @returns {Function} - action creator
 */
export function authenticateUserWithSecondSystem (authenticationToken) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestSecondSystemAuthentication());

    ApiService.post('/api/authenticate', authenticationToken)
      .then(payload => dispatch(secondSystemAuthenticateSuccess(payload)))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided I was trying to make it too complex, I've opted to have one action called `authenticateUser` that gets called on click and that handles the logic to login to the first provider and then the second.